# selecting a view from another view in teradata

Tags: view, teradata

Have created a view, vw2 on vw1 using below syntax.

replace view tst_t1_vws.vw2
as
sel * from tst_t1_vws.vw1

after creating the second view, added few more fields to the inner view, vw1.
but now when i select records from outer view vw2,it is not dispalying recently added columns.
what can be the reason?

Comment: You have to refresh the second view.  Just drop and re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is based on Standard SQL.

When a view is created the ***** is resolved to the current column list. Now you change the base table/view definition, but the column list is still the same.

You simply need to re-run the REPLACE VIEW.